# Where a shadow plane should be defined in Scenekit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

It's so confusing to me, would be grateful if anyone help me on it.
I have a shadow plane to show the shadow below the AR object. I read some article that they define this shadow in `viewDidLoad`and add it as the child bode to `sceneView.scene`. The question is, it should be defined only once for the floor surface?

for instance, I can add the shadow plane to `renderer(_:didAdd:for:)`, it call it once when a new surface is detected. That is so cool for me.  But the position of the shadow plane should be changed as well? can someone explain it to me that where it should be defined and wehere/when it should be updated?

here how I define the shadow plane

```
private func addShadowPlane(node: SCNNode, planeAnchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {
    
    let anchorX = planeAnchor.center.x
    let anchorY: planeAnchor.center.y
    let anchorZ = planeAnchor.center.z
            
    let floor = SCNFloor()
    let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
    floorNode.position = SCNVector3(anchorX, anchorY, anchorZ)
    
    floor.length = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)
    floor.width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
    floor.reflectivity = 0
    floor.materials = [shadowMaterialStandard()]
    node.addChildNode(floorNode)
}


func shadowMaterialStandard() -> SCNMaterial {
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.lightingModel = .physicallyBased
    material.writesToDepthBuffer = true
    material.readsFromDepthBuffer = true
    material.colorBufferWriteMask = []
    return material
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you might run into is: Do you want one single shadow plane in a kind of initial defined position and then remains there (or can be repositioned). Or do you want a lots of shadow planes, like on any surface captured with the ARKit? The problem might be, that all those planes will not be exact and accurate to the surfaces on top they are created (just more or less). You can make more accurate shapes for surfaces, but they are built up in an ongoing process and need more time to complete (imagine you scan a table by walking around). I also did some ARApps with Shadow planes. I usually create one single shadow plane (like 20x20 meters) on my request using a focus square. I fetch the worldPosition from the focus square, then I add a plane to that location using Scenekit (and not the Renderer for plane anchors). Keep in mind, there are many ways to do this. There is no best way.

Try to study this Apple Sample App for more information on placing objects, casting shadows etc:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/environmental_analysis/placing_objects_and_handling_3d_interaction

Comment: Thank you @ZAY, my first attempt was, creating shadow plane in every surfaces, but if there is a shadow on a real table surface and move an AR object beside that table, that shadow plane on the table makes a cut on the object beside it. That is why I'm also thinking to use on single plane. Thanks to you, I know now that I can use focus share to add it.  I did something like that before, but the shadow was too far from the object after it, could you provide me an example of the lighting on a single shadow plane

Comment: If your shadow plane is transparent, i recommend you to use a directional light source that cast .deferred shadows. The Plane material should be a pure white as diffuse color and the colorBufferWriteMask an empty array like you did [ ]. I will look for an example code ASAP :)